# How to give oval shape to UIView with shadow

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, shadow, shapes

How to make uiview with oval shape at bottom side only with shadow

[image: How to make uiview with oval shape at bottom side only with shadow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `UIBezierPath` for this. Here is an example (just need to play with the values):

```
   let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
    layer.shadowRadius = 5
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    layer.shadowRadius = 2
    view.layer.addSublayer(layer)

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: .zero)
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: view.frame.maxX, y: 0))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: view.frame.maxX, y: 50))
    path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 50), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: view.frame.midX, y: 70))
    path.close()

    layer.path = path.cgPath
```

and result:

[image]